# Add elements in a horizontal scroll view in android studio

Tags: java, android

I'm working with this code and I've a problem when adding elements (dynamically) to the scrollview (horizontal).

In the final program I will have to have multiple horizontal scrolls in a single vertical scroll (so this is just a part of the my app's code).

This is the xml, and this is ok.

```
 <ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
    android:layout_width="390dp"
    android:layout_height="315dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.476"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.616">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="SONO UN TITOLO" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/some_text"
            android:layout_width="390dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/title"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scroll_h"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/some_text">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout_orizzontale"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
            </LinearLayout>

        </HorizontalScrollView>



    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Now in java i have a code like this:

```
LinearLayout a = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_orizzontale);
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        Button tv = new Button(getApplicationContext());
        tv.setText(" hello ");
        a.addView(tv);
    }
```

The problem is that if I add elements via xml, they show up, but the java code doesn't work..

Comment: Please don't tag questions with the android-studio tag just because you use it: the Android Studio tag should **only** be used when you have questions about the IDE itself, and not any code you write (or want to write) in it. See [when is it appropriate to remove an IDE tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315196/6296561), [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354427/6296561), and [the tagging guide](/help/tagging). Use [android] or other relevant tags instead.

Comment: You may try invalidate() after you add your views to force the UI.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest this code: I added some comments to slightly explain it. I have done 2 solutions you can choose the one adapted to what you will do next with the buttons added.
Solution 1:

```
LinearLayout a = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_orizzontale);
//added an ArrayList to store the Buttons if you want to use it later.
ArrayList<Button> listOfButtons = new ArrayList<Buttons>();
Button tv = new Button(getApplicationContext());
tv.setText(" hello "+0);
//added id for the rules
tv.setId(View.generateViewId());
listOfButtons.add(tv);
a.addView(tv);
for(int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
  LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
  Button tv = new Button(getApplicationContext());
  tv.setText(" hello "+i);
  tv.setId(View.generateViewId());
  layoutParams.addRule(LinearLayout.BELOW,listOfButtons.get(i-1).getId());
  listOfButtons.add(tv);
  a.addView(tv,layoutParams);
}
```

Solution 2  without ArrayList

```
  LinearLayout a = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_orizzontale);
  Button tv = new Button(getApplicationContext());
  Button tempButton;
  tv.setText(" hello "+0);
  //added id for the rules
  tv.setId(View.generateViewId());
  tempButton=tv;
  a.addView(tv);
  for(int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    Button tv = new Button(getApplicationContext());
    tv.setText(" hello "+i);
    tv.setId(View.generateViewId());
    layoutParams.addRule(LinearLayout.BELOW,tempButton.getId());
    temp=tv;
    a.addView(tv,layoutParams);
  }
```

Hope this solves your problem.
EDIT : this is website my help understand the function LayoutParams()
[developer.android](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams#LayoutParams(android.content.Context,%20android.util.AttributeSet))

Comment: Thank you for these examples, but the problem in my case was that I'haven't set width and height with `getLayoutParams()`